# magento_root_folder/var/tmp/_cache low disk space

Tags: magento2, cache

I’ve found that _cache directory is consuming 17GB of space which is under magento_root_folder/var/tmp/ directory. I removed it, but after 2 days, I’ve again received an alert regarding low disk space on magento_root_folder/var/tmp/
[image]

I stuck on it, hope anyone's help

Comment: You have to create cronjob which will delete every day mid night. On temp , CSS and js merge is saved Which is create based on customer session

Answer (score 1):

The Magento/Adobe-suggested permissions (see [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/deployment/file-system-permissions.html)) make the pub/static file un-writable, so when the system tries to make a _cache folder and put .css and .js merge files in it, it can't and has to revert to the magento/var/tmp folder - and then it keeps adding those files again and again ad nauseam.

Solution:

```
chmod 664 pub/static
```

(644 might do the job)

This is addressed, but not solved, [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13225)